# Flink Kafka Table API for python with JAAS

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-flink, jaas, sasl

I am using Flink 1.11.2 version Python Table API to connect to Kafka Topic using SASL protocol but it fails with following error. I tried same properties in Flink java version, and I am able to connect. Has anyone faced this issue and how did you resolve it?

```
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: unable to find LoginModule class: org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule
```

Settings:

```
kafka = Kafka()\
        .version("universal") \
        .topic("test_topic")\
        .property("group.id", "consumer_group")\
        .property("security.protocol", "SASL_PLAINTEXT")\
        .property("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN")\
        .property("bootstrap.servers",
                  "<remoteIP>:9093")\
        .property("sasl.jaas.config",
                  "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"user\" "
                  "password=\"abc\";")\
        .start_from_latest()
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please provide your kafka settings?

Comment: updated with settings.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into that error, not in the Python API, but in the JVM (I do think it is the same issue), that was resolved by explicitly adding a dependency to the kafka-clients (2.8.0 at the time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

I see this question is extremely old, but also had an issue determining how to configure for SASL without *org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule*.

Eventually got it working with the following config, and posting it here for reference (Utilizing the Table API in python via SQL connector instruction):

```py
  KAFKA_SERVERS = os.getenv('KAFKA_BS_SERVERS',"kafka-0-external:9094,kafka-1- external:9094,kafka-2-external:9094,kafka-3-external:9094,kafka-4- external:9094").split(',')
  KAFKA_USERNAME = "XXX"
  KAFKA_PASSWORD = "pass"
  KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC = 'topic'

  source_ddl = f"""
            CREATE TABLE source_table(
                entry STRING
            ) WITH (
              'connector' = 'kafka',
              'topic' = '{KAFKA_SOURCE_TOPIC}',
              'properties.bootstrap.servers' = '{','.join(KAFKA_SERVERS)}',
              'properties.group.id' = 'testgroup12',
              'properties.sasl.mechanism' = 'PLAIN',
              'properties.security.protocol' = 'SASL_PLAINTEXT',
              'properties.sasl.jaas.config' = 'org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"{KAFKA_USERNAME}\" password=\"{KAFKA_PASSWORD}\";',
              'scan.startup.mode' = 'latest-offset',
              'format' = 'raw'
            )
            """

  env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
  env.add_jars("file:///opt/flink/lib_py/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.12-1.14.0.jar")
  settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance()\
                      .in_streaming_mode()\
                      .use_blink_planner()\
                      .build()

  t_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment= env, environment_settings=settings)
  t_env.execute_sql(source_ddl).wait()
```